# Real forms of complex vector spaces and $\mathbb{C}$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

A real form $W$ of a complex vector space $V$ is a real subspace s.t. $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}W \cong V$ by $a\otimes x \longrightarrow ax$, or equivalently there is an $\mathbb{R}$-basis of $W$ that is also a $\mathbb{C}$-basis of $V$.

There is a fact that every complex vector space has a real form.

For example, $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are real forms of $\mathbb{C}^n$, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ respectively. The last two examples are not only real vector spaces but real subalgebras.

So, I'm wondering whether any complex associative algebra $A$ has a real form, i.e. a real subalgebra $B$ s.t. $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}B \cong A$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algbras? Is there any counterexample?

Answer (score 3):

I am very sure that there are counterexamples, but haven't found one so far. In fact, I have found many examples which surprisingly have a real form. I share them here so that others interested in this problem won't have to fall for the same traps. I assume any algebra to be unital.

1. If $G$ is any monoid, then the monoid algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ has a real form. This applies in particular to free commutative algebras (i.e. polynomial rings in any set of variables) as well as to free algebras.
2. The class of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with a real form is closed under arbitrary products and tensor products. Notice that although tensoring with a field extension doesn't have to preserve infinite products, this is the case for finite field extensions such as $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$.
3. A $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $A$ has a real form if and only if there is a homomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras ${}^* : A \to A$ which is an involution (i.e. $a=(a^*)^*$) and satisfies $(\lambda a)^* = \overline{\lambda} a^*$. Notice the similarity to the notion of a [*-algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2a-algebra), the difference is that we demand $(ab)^* = a^* b^*$. Proof: "$\Rightarrow$" On $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} B$ define $(\lambda \otimes b)^* := \overline{\lambda} \otimes b$. "$\Leftarrow$" Consider the real subalgebra $B=\{a \in A : a^*=a\}$. Every $a \in A$ has a unique representation as $a=r + is$ with $r,s \in B$, namely $r = \frac{a+a^*}{2}$ and $s=\frac{a-a^*}{2i}$. Thus $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} B \cong A$. $\square$
4. If $X$ is any topological space, then $C(X,\mathbb{C})$ has a real form, namely $C(X,\mathbb{R})$. In fact, we have the involution given by taking the complex conjugate pointwise.
5. If $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}^k$ is a (Edit: symmetric) domain, then the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of holomorphic functions $D \to \mathbb{C}$ has an involution and therefore a real form: Apply the complex conjugation to the coefficients of a power series expansion.
6. If $B$ is any set of variables, then the function field $\mathbb{C}(B)$ has a real form. More generally, if $L/K$ is an algebraic field extension, then $L \otimes_K K(B) \cong L(B)$.
7. If $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, then $\mathbb{C}[x]/(f)$ has a real form. In fact, this algebra is isomorphic to $\prod_i \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^{k_i})$ if $k_i$ is the multiplicity of the $i$th root of $f$, and $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^{k_i}) = \mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^{k_i})$.
8. I believe that there must be a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f)$ has no real form. In the language of algebraic geometry, this means that the complex curve $V(f)$ is not definable over $\mathbb{R}$. In the literature I could only find information about  projective curves. So let's take a random polynomial (honestly, I just make it up while writing this) $f = x^3 + i x y + y^2 x + i$. Substituting $y$ with $iy$ gives $f' = x^3-xy - y^2 x + i$. Substituting $x$ with $ix$ gives $f''=-i x^3-ixy - iy^2 x + i$. Thus, $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(-x^3-xy-y^2 x + 1)$ is a real form. This kind of substitution has worked in all random examples that I've tried.

Comment: In example 5., conjugating the coefficients of a power series expansion only works if the domain is symmetric (with respect to $\mathfrak{z}_0 + \mathbb{R}^k$). If we conjugate the coefficients in the expansion about $\mathfrak{z}_0$, we get $$g(\mathfrak{z}) = \overline{f(\mathfrak{z}_0 + \overline{\mathfrak{z}-\mathfrak{z}_0})},$$ defined on $\mathfrak{z}_0 + \overline{D - \mathfrak{z}_0}$, which generally is not $D$.

Comment: 7 seems a little off... e.g. $f=x^2$

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected both.

Comment: In your (8), isn't the problem just that you managed to take a polynomial where the odd-degree terms are 'real' and the even-degree terms are 'pure imaginary' so that the simple substitution worked things out?  If you choose your polynomial with more care, it seems like you can ensure that you'll always have 'cross terms'...

Comment: Can you name such an example? For example $x^2+iy^2$ doesn't fit to your description, but still the substitution $\sqrt{i }y$ for $y$ works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sketch of a construction:

Let $k$ be a perfect field. The $j$-invariant provides a map
$$j : \{\text{elliptic curves over } k\}/~{\cong} \to k$$
which is bijective when $k$ is algebraically closed. It commutes with base change (since the $j$-invariant can be computed from the Weierstrass equation). Now take an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ with $j$-invariant in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$. Its function field is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra which is not induced by an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, since this would have to be the function field of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{R}$ which induces the given one over $\mathbb{C}$. But then it would have $j$-invariant in $\mathbb{R}$, a contradiction.